# React: How to implement Component.SubComponent

Tags: reactjs

I saw some example code like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import MyComp from 'my-comp'

const MySubComp = MyComp.MySubComp

class Page extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MyComp>
        <MySubComp/>
      </MyComp>
      )
  }
}
```

How to implement the syntax `MyComp.MySubComp`?

Does it has a terminology?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your example, `MySubComp` is a static class member of `MyComp`, you can easily implement it like that :

```
export default class MyComp extends Component {
   // ...
}

MyComp.MySubComp = class MySubComp extends Component {
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Similarly to Freez's answer, for functional components you can append the sub-component to it like so:

```
export default function MyComp(props) {
    return (
        <div>Main component</div>
    );
}

MyComp.MySubComp = function MySubComp(props) {
    return (
        <div>Sub component</div>
    );
}

// Alternative way
MyComp.MySubComp = (props) => <div>Sub component</div>
```

They can be consumed this way:

```
<MyComp>
    <MyComp.MySubComp />
</MyComp>
```

Note: The first way repeats the name of the component. The explanation for that is the first name is the attached sub-name of the other function, and the second name is the name of the actual component, which will be displayed in React Dev Tools. Without it, dev tools will just display "Anonymous" instead.

Comment: I have issues with hot reload when doing changes inside sub-component. Any ideas why? It is working normally when it is exported as a normal component.

Comment: @Dawe Haven't really had issues myself but you can try `MyComp.MySubComp = function MySubComp(props) {}` because otherwise the name of the component becomes "anonymous" in the dev tools, so I generally do it this way instead.